# Adding last_name , first_name to default django_registration(not redux)

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I use django-registration 1.0(i am not sure about it, but i know it is the lates version)So, i want to make user enter his own first_name and last_name, during his registration, and store them with other(username, email, pass) to **User**
model. So i created my own form ,in **forms.py** wich inherists from default django **RegistrationForm**, and add some extra fields

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.forms.fields import CharField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UpdatedRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    first_name = CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = CharField(max_length=30)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

def save(self, commit = True):
    user = super(UpdatedRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    if commit:
        user.save()
        return user
```

Then i put my new form to **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from accounts.views import home_page, admin_panel
from accounts.forms import UpdatedRegistrationForm
from registration.views import RegistrationView

class RegistrationViewUniqueEmail(RegistrationView):
    form_class = UpdatedRegistrationForm

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/', home_page),
    url(r'^admin_pannel/',admin_panel),
    url(r'^register/$', RegistrationViewUniqueEmail.as_view(),               name='registration_register'),
url(r'', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
]
```

When i run my server, and visit *127.0.0.1:8000/register/* i saw, that extra fields was added to my form [register form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvivu.png)

Then i press register, and i saw an error
[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx5fX.png)
But i also saw that data was sent.
So, i think that the reason may be in not override **init**() method. But i dont know how to do this, so may there is the another reason. Please, help me with this.
errors:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/

Django Version: 1.8.5
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'social_auth',
 'accounts',
 'rest_framework')
Installed Middleware:
('accounts.middleware_log.MiddleWareLog',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request,     *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/registration/views.py" in     dispatch
  79.         return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request,     *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/registration/views.py" in     post
  35.             return self.form_valid(request, form)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/registration/views.py" in     form_valid
  82.         new_user = self.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/registration/views.py" in     register
  109.         raise NotImplementedError

Exception Type: NotImplementedError at /register/
Exception Value:
```

Sorry for my very bad english.

Comment: So, i edit my post, and i think that i user django-registration version 1.0 , if help me to check it, it will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the simple backend, you should subclass the view from that backend. You are currently using the base `RegistrationView`, which does not implement a `register` method.

Instead of importing

```
from registration.views import RegistrationView
```

you should try

```
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView
```

django-registration will hopefully [have a new release soon](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2015/aug/13/django-registration/), but at the moment it hasn't had a new release for some time. The latest release might not work with recent versions of Django, in which case you might have more success with django-registration-redux.